# I18n - JSF variable value translation

Tags: java, jsf, internationalization

I am using Bundle Internationalization in my project. I have initialized bundle via

```
<f:loadBundle basename="ui.all.bundles.AppResources_en" var="msg"/>
```

When i need to translate some text, i am using a key to resourceBundle, to get a value of it, for example: #{msg.someText}. But, now i want to translate text, which key is a value of another variable. For example:

I have variable **String textToTransl**. It`s value is **status_booked**. In my AppResources is defined, that **status_booked** means "It is booked!", so, when i am pointing it to *#{msg.textToTransl}* i need to see "It is booked!"

How can i make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
value="#{msg[currentDoc.textToTransl]}"
```

Comment: if my textToTransl is in #{currentDoc.textToTransl}, then i can do #{msg[#{currentDoc.textToTransl}]}?

Answer (score 0):

```
 ui.all.bundles.AppResources
```

Don't include the locale (`_en`) in the resource name. The resource bundle code should resolve the locale-specific bundle based on the request locale.

Comment: I need to include locale name, because all project still is only in English. But question was not about that.

Comment: @Yurish - it's called `basename` because you shouldn't include the locale suffix :)